# DirectX 11 Visual Install Failure

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 and C++.
I am learning direct X programming and is trying to run the example files.
I am using the book "Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11"( Frank D.Luna).

I am trying to run an example demo that is testing if Direct X works on VC and if I (the student) get's it or not. The program does not run it returns errors.

A month ago I defragmented, deleted everything and rebooted my computer.
Before that when I originally tried to install and run and initiate DirectX 11 it worked fine.
Now when I installed VS and Direct X 11 again,  I do the same thing as I did it before and now it does not work.
The basic error is that is succeeds with debug but not with running, when I run the program I get a blank window and a error could not create DirectX device.

Should I try reinstalling all Visual Studio versions
and Direct X11,  then install first visual and then Direct X?
If I uninstall all Visual Studio will my computer take damage?
Is the fault with my graphic card which is out of date?
Is it because I have an old version of Windows 7?

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: FalsePromise, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2014-07-29 19:25:38.
1>_PrepareForClean:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\FalsePromise.lastbuildstate".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\FalsePromise.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  xnacollision.cpp
1>  Waves.cpp
1>  TextureMgr.cpp
1>  MathHelper.cpp
1>  LightHelper.cpp
1>  GeometryGenerator.cpp
1>  GameTimer.cpp
1>  d3dUtil.cpp
1>  d3dApp.cpp
1>  Camera.cpp
1>  BoxDemo.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>BoxDemo.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification
1>     Creating library C:\Users\Claes\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FalsePromise\Debug\FalsePromise.lib and object C:\Users\Claes\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FalsePromise\Debug\FalsePromise.exp
1>Effects11d.lib(d3dx11dbg.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Claes\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FalsePromise\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
1>Effects11d.lib(d3dxGlobal.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Claes\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FalsePromise\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectAPI.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Claes\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FalsePromise\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectLoad.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Claes\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FalsePromise\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectNonRuntime.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Claes\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FalsePromise\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectReflection.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Claes\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FalsePromise\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectRuntime.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Claes\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FalsePromise\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
1>  FalsePromise.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Claes\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FalsePromise\Debug\FalsePromise.exe
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\FalsePromise.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "Debug\FalsePromise.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:10.16
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========



//***************************************************************************************
// BoxDemo.cpp by Frank Luna (C) 2011 All Rights Reserved.
//
// Demonstrates rendering a colored box.
//
// Controls:
//      Hold the left mouse button down and move the mouse to rotate.
//      Hold the right mouse button down to zoom in and out.
//
//***************************************************************************************

#include "d3dApp.h"
#include "d3dx11Effect.h"
#include "MathHelper.h"

struct Vertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
};

class BoxApp : public D3DApp
{
public:
    BoxApp(HINSTANCE hInstance);
    ~BoxApp();

    bool Init();
    void OnResize();
    void UpdateScene(float dt);
    void DrawScene(); 

    void OnMouseDown(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y);
    void OnMouseUp(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y);
    void OnMouseMove(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y);

private:
    void BuildGeometryBuffers();
    void BuildFX();
    void BuildVertexLayout();

private:
    ID3D11Buffer* mBoxVB;
    ID3D11Buffer* mBoxIB;

    ID3DX11Effect* mFX;
    ID3DX11EffectTechnique* mTech;
    ID3DX11EffectMatrixVariable* mfxWorldViewProj;

    ID3D11InputLayout* mInputLayout;

    XMFLOAT4X4 mWorld;
    XMFLOAT4X4 mView;
    XMFLOAT4X4 mProj;

    float mTheta;
    float mPhi;
    float mRadius;

    POINT mLastMousePos;
};

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance,
                   PSTR cmdLine, int showCmd)
{
    // Enable run-time memory check for debug builds.
#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
    _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
#endif

    BoxApp theApp(hInstance);

    if( !theApp.Init() )
        return 0;

    return theApp.Run();
}


BoxApp::BoxApp(HINSTANCE hInstance)
: D3DApp(hInstance), mBoxVB(0), mBoxIB(0), mFX(0), mTech(0),
  mfxWorldViewProj(0), mInputLayout(0), 
  mTheta(1.5f*MathHelper::Pi), mPhi(0.25f*MathHelper::Pi), mRadius(5.0f)
{
    mMainWndCaption = L"Box Demo";

    mLastMousePos.x = 0;
    mLastMousePos.y = 0;

    XMMATRIX I = XMMatrixIdentity();
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&mWorld, I);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&mView, I);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&mProj, I);
}

BoxApp::~BoxApp()
{
    ReleaseCOM(mBoxVB);
    ReleaseCOM(mBoxIB);
    ReleaseCOM(mFX);
    ReleaseCOM(mInputLayout);
}

bool BoxApp::Init()
{
    if(!D3DApp::Init())
        return false;

    BuildGeometryBuffers();
    BuildFX();
    BuildVertexLayout();

    return true;
}

void BoxApp::OnResize()
{
    D3DApp::OnResize();

    // The window resized, so update the aspect ratio and recompute the projection matrix.
    XMMATRIX P = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(0.25f*MathHelper::Pi, AspectRatio(), 1.0f, 1000.0f);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&mProj, P);
}

void BoxApp::UpdateScene(float dt)
{
    // Convert Spherical to Cartesian coordinates.
    float x = mRadius*sinf(mPhi)*cosf(mTheta);
    float z = mRadius*sinf(mPhi)*sinf(mTheta);
    float y = mRadius*cosf(mPhi);

    // Build the view matrix.
    XMVECTOR pos    = XMVectorSet(x, y, z, 1.0f);
    XMVECTOR target = XMVectorZero();
    XMVECTOR up     = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    XMMATRIX V = XMMatrixLookAtLH(pos, target, up);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&mView, V);
}

void BoxApp::DrawScene()
{
    md3dImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(mRenderTargetView, reinterpret_cast<const float*>(&Colors::LightSteelBlue));
    md3dImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH|D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

    md3dImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(mInputLayout);
    md3dImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    md3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &mBoxVB, &stride, &offset);
    md3dImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(mBoxIB, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    // Set constants
    XMMATRIX world = XMLoadFloat4x4(&mWorld);
    XMMATRIX view  = XMLoadFloat4x4(&mView);
    XMMATRIX proj  = XMLoadFloat4x4(&mProj);
    XMMATRIX worldViewProj = world*view*proj;

    mfxWorldViewProj->SetMatrix(reinterpret_cast<float*>(&worldViewProj));

    D3DX11_TECHNIQUE_DESC techDesc;
    mTech->GetDesc( &techDesc );
    for(UINT p = 0; p < techDesc.Passes; ++p)
    {
        mTech->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0, md3dImmediateContext);

        // 36 indices for the box.
        md3dImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);
    }

    HR(mSwapChain->Present(0, 0));
}

void BoxApp::OnMouseDown(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y)
{
    mLastMousePos.x = x;
    mLastMousePos.y = y;

    SetCapture(mhMainWnd);
}

void BoxApp::OnMouseUp(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y)
{
    ReleaseCapture();
}

void BoxApp::OnMouseMove(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y)
{
    if( (btnState & MK_LBUTTON) != 0 )
    {
        // Make each pixel correspond to a quarter of a degree.
        float dx = XMConvertToRadians(0.25f*static_cast<float>(x - mLastMousePos.x));
        float dy = XMConvertToRadians(0.25f*static_cast<float>(y - mLastMousePos.y));

        // Update angles based on input to orbit camera around box.
        mTheta += dx;
        mPhi   += dy;

        // Restrict the angle mPhi.
        mPhi = MathHelper::Clamp(mPhi, 0.1f, MathHelper::Pi-0.1f);
    }
    else if( (btnState & MK_RBUTTON) != 0 )
    {
        // Make each pixel correspond to 0.005 unit in the scene.
        float dx = 0.005f*static_cast<float>(x - mLastMousePos.x);
        float dy = 0.005f*static_cast<float>(y - mLastMousePos.y);

        // Update the camera radius based on input.
        mRadius += dx - dy;

        // Restrict the radius.
        mRadius = MathHelper::Clamp(mRadius, 3.0f, 15.0f);
    }

    mLastMousePos.x = x;
    mLastMousePos.y = y;
}

void BoxApp::BuildGeometryBuffers()
{
    // Create vertex buffer
    Vertex vertices[] =
    {
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::White   },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Black   },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Red     },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Green   },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Blue    },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Yellow  },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Cyan    },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), (const float*)&Colors::Magenta }
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
    vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 8;
    vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
    vbd.StructureByteStride = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
    vinitData.pSysMem = vertices;
    HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &mBoxVB));


    // Create the index buffer

    UINT indices[] = {
        // front face
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 2, 3,

        // back face
        4, 6, 5,
        4, 7, 6,

        // left face
        4, 5, 1,
        4, 1, 0,

        // right face
        3, 2, 6,
        3, 6, 7,

        // top face
        1, 5, 6,
        1, 6, 2,

        // bottom face
        4, 0, 3, 
        4, 3, 7
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibd;
    ibd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(UINT) * 36;
    ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    ibd.MiscFlags = 0;
    ibd.StructureByteStride = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;
    iinitData.pSysMem = indices;
    HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&ibd, &iinitData, &mBoxIB));
}

void BoxApp::BuildFX()
{
    DWORD shaderFlags = 0;
#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
    shaderFlags |= D3D10_SHADER_DEBUG;
    shaderFlags |= D3D10_SHADER_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION;
#endif

    ID3D10Blob* compiledShader = 0;
    ID3D10Blob* compilationMsgs = 0;
    HRESULT hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"FX/color.fx", 0, 0, 0, "fx_5_0", shaderFlags, 
        0, 0, &compiledShader, &compilationMsgs, 0);

    // compilationMsgs can store errors or warnings.
    if( compilationMsgs != 0 )
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, (char*)compilationMsgs->GetBufferPointer(), 0, 0);
        ReleaseCOM(compilationMsgs);
    }

    // Even if there are no compilationMsgs, check to make sure there were no other errors.
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        DXTrace(__FILE__, (DWORD)__LINE__, hr, L"D3DX11CompileFromFile", true);
    }

    HR(D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(compiledShader->GetBufferPointer(), compiledShader->GetBufferSize(), 
        0, md3dDevice, &mFX));

    // Done with compiled shader.
    ReleaseCOM(compiledShader);

    mTech    = mFX->GetTechniqueByName("ColorTech");
    mfxWorldViewProj = mFX->GetVariableByName("gWorldViewProj")->AsMatrix();
}

void BoxApp::BuildVertexLayout()
{
    // Create the vertex input layout.
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertexDesc[] =
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"COLOR",    0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };

    // Create the input layout
    D3DX11_PASS_DESC passDesc;
    mTech->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&passDesc);
    HR(md3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(vertexDesc, 2, passDesc.pIAInputSignature, 
        passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize, &mInputLayout));
}
```

Comment: What error in particular are you getting? That might be a hint. You can try building and running [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tutorial-Win32-829979ef) sample to sanity check your system.

Comment: By "install DirectX" I assume you mean the DirectX SDK or perhaps the DirectX End User Runtime. Neither of these actually "install DirectX". They would just install D3DX11 and some other optional bits. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx) blog post. In this case you are calling "D3DX11CompileFromFile" which requires D3DX11*.DLL and then indirectly requires D3DCompile*.DLL. Unfortunately, Frank's book is old enough he's relying on legacy stuff throughout.